# Discrete time non-linear time invariant system dynamics descriptions (state-space or input-output relationship)

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations, dynamical-systems, control-theory, nonlinear-system

For the sake of simplicity the following notation $a_k := a(k)$ is assumed for time sequences.

A completely general discrete-time (DT) non-linear(NL) time-invariant (TI) dynamical system can be described with a system of vector difference equations, where $x(k)$ is the system state, $u(k)$ is the system input and $y(k)$ is the system output:
$$\begin{cases} x(k+1) = f(x(k),u(k))\\ y(k) = g(x(k), u(k)) \end{cases} \quad\forall k\ge0$$
$f$ and $g$ are general non linear functions.

The first equation is very close to a general autonomous non linear differential equation with $\dot x(t)=f(x(t),u(t))$ where $u(t)$ is the source term.

Now, the same dynamical DT NL TI system could be described also through an input output relationship, involving more among their'samples' (current and past):
$$y(k) = h(y(k-1),y(k-2),...,y(k-n),u(k),u(k-1),...,u(k-m)), \quad\forall k\ge0$$ where again, $h$ is a general non linear function, and $n,m$ are integer positive values.

How can one prove that this input-relationship form is equivalent to the former state-space representation, at least when $x(0)=0$ (without any care about a possible relationship between $f,g$ and $h$)?

EDIT:
And, at least, how can one be sure that the IO relationship involves finite past samples and not all the past samples (since the initial time instant)?

Answer (score 1):

One can do this by for example defining the state vector as follows,

$$
x(k) = \begin{bmatrix}
y(k) \\ y(k-1) \\ \vdots \\ y(k-n+1) \\
u(k-1) \\ u(k-2) \\ \vdots \\ u(k-m+1)
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

By using your second update formula for $y(k)$, one can quite easily find $f(x(k),u(k))$, because it should describe $x(k+1)$. Assuming that $y(k)$ is a vector of length $l$, then for the top $l$ states you can just use the second update formula (but increment the value of $k$ by one), since all the required inputs for $h(\cdot)$ are present in $x(k)$ and $u(k)$. The remaining states will just be a down shift of the already known states of $x(k)$, omitting $y(k-n+1)$ when the history of $u(k)$ starts, where instead $u(k)$ is inserted. After this the down shifting of the already known states of $x(k)$ continues, until the end of the state vector, omitting $u(k-m+1)$. And $g(x(k),u(k))$ should be trivial as well, namely just take the top state(s) of $x(k)$.

Comment: Thank you, but I'd like to derive the IO relationship from a general state space representation, and I want to figure out the reason why, if the state has $n$ components (system of order $n$) then the obtained IO relationship expresses a link between the output and its past samples up to $n$ backward shift.